# Terminal startup error: object 0x7fe089600420: pointer being freed was not allocated

Tags: macos, unix, terminal

I have recently tried opening up Terminal and have this come up:

```
Last login: Tue Jun  9 13:11:07 on console
login(67618,0x7fff71d59300) malloc: *** error for object 0x7fe089600420: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

[Process completed]
```

But it also does not let me type in any commands.
I do not know what caused this, but if you don't mind helping me with it, please do!

Thanks in advance -CamelInATardis

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It happens to me and that what i did to resolve it:
open "Disk Utility" app and chose "Repair Disk Permissions".